# How to do a redirecting page while having a preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

first problem is that if i put the e.preventDefault it dont redirect to the homeadmin.php when successfully login since it call the ajax successfully and there's no error on my validation it can validate,

second problem is that i need to use e.preventDefault() to show also the error message on the validation on the client side which is contradicting to the first problem

and thats my concern only using e.preventDefault() and there's no problem to the validation, i just want to redirec to the other page after successfully login and show validation error when validating the form

what i want to be the result is that when user successfully login it redirect to the other page and when user has an error on login it dont redirect to the other page but to show the error-massage validation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginformid').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        var formdata = new FormData(this);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../controller/loginquery.php',
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(respoadd) {
                if (respoadd.success === 'login') {
                    window.location.replace('../admin/homeadmin.php');
                } else {
                    $('#username-error').html(respoadd.username_error);
                    $('#password-error').html(respoadd.password_error);
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

$username_error = '';
$password_error ='';
$success = '';


try{
    if(strlen($username) < 5 || strlen($username) > 255){
        $username_error = "This field require with 5 minimum character not greater than 255";
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 5 || strlen($password) > 255){
        $password_error = "This field require with 5 minimum character not greater than 255";
    }
    if($username_error === '' && $password_error === ''){
        $queryvalidate = "SELECT * FROM tbl_userinfo WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $queryvalidate);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1){
            $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $stored_password_hash = $user_data['password'];
            if(password_verify($password, $stored_password_hash)){
                $success = "login";
                $_SESSION['status'] = 'valid';
                echo "<script>window.location.href ='../admin/homeadmin.php'</script>";
            }
            else{
                $password_error = "The password is not match with useranme";
                $_SESSION['status'] = 'invalid';
            }
        }
        else{
            $username_error = "Username does not exist";
            $_SESSION['status'] = 'invalid';
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
    $output = array(
        'username_error' => $username_error,
        'password_error' => $password_error,
        'success' => $success
    );
    echo json_encode($output);   

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'error page';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` when using a prepared statement with parameters. Special characters are already escaped when using parameters, you'll escape them twice this way.

Comment: I think your JavaScript should do what you want. `window.location.replace()` will redirect to the other page.

Comment: -@Barmar noted sir, i updated the code

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the normal form submission. It won't prevent the redirection that you do in the `success:` function.

Comment: @Barmar noted sir, i updated the code about the mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: You already said that.

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere. You say what you want to do, and it looks like the code does what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: in your php code `if(password_verify($password, $stored_password_hash)){...` you do `echo "<script>window.location.href ='../admin/homeadmin.php'</script>";` remove it as it's not a JSON which is expected on the client side.

Comment: @Barmar but still dont  dont redirect when i see the call of ajax from the server side using console.log it says the url correct also the loging success message but it dont redirect to the page

Comment: I can't see any reason for that. If `respoadd.success === 'login'` is true, it should do the redirect. If you put `console.log("redirecting")` in that `if` block, do you see the message?

Comment: @AlnoorManoga: *"but still dont [...] redirect"* - That operation only happens conditionally.  Is that condition being met?  Now is a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  You can check the browser console for any errors at all, check the network tab to observe the AJAX request/response, and use the script debugger to place breakpoints in your functions and step through the code line-by-line to observe its runtime behavior and the values of your variables.  When you do this, which specific operation produces an unexpected result?

Comment: @Barmar yes it shows on console.log about the url path of directing page and also the "LOGIN" message means it successfully login but it dont redirect to the other page

Comment: I'm out of ideas. If it's going into that `if` block, it has to call `window.location.replace()`, and this will cause the redirect.

Comment: its ok now i solved the problem i just change the exchange their position $success = "login"; $_SESSION['status'] = 'valid'; since the valid has the session first, once the echo session is valid then it will redirect to the other page that is why when it print login it cant redirect to the other page because it has no valid session to enter to the page, so i solved it now, thank you all much loveee <3

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click",e=>{
  e.preventDefault()
  location.href = "/test"
});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Do you think that assigning to `location.href` is different from calling `window.location.replace()`?

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong, and how your code fixes it. It would be best if you posted an edited version of their code, not something generic like this that has nothing to do with their HTML.

Comment: its ok now i solved the problem i just change the exchange their position    $success = "login";
                $_SESSION['status'] = 'valid'; since the valid has the session first,  once the echo session is valid then it will redirect to the other page that is why when it print login it cant redirect to the other page because it has no valid session to enter to the page, so i solved it now, thank you all much loveee <3